# How to compare a value in array to get the right index?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I got a bit stuck in a logic function where I have an array with time time position. I want to check if current position fits between two position values then return the index of current position.

So the array looks like this;

```
const PLAYLIST = [{"position":"01:35"}, {"position":"05:44"}, {"position":"09:14"}, {"position":"12:00"}]
```

now current position is `07:22` so it fits between `{"position":"05:44"}` and `{"position":"09:14"}` so it should return index 1

Comment: @Andreas To check currentPosition if its greater than item position in a filter function than getting the length of objects in the returned array but is not returning the right number

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{
  "position": "01:35"
}, {
  "position": "05:44"
}, {
  "position": "09:14"
}, {
  "position": "12:00"
}]

var currentPosition = "09:22";

var closestSmallIndex = fetchClosestIndex(currentPosition);

console.log(closestSmallIndex)

function fetchClosestIndex(currentPosition) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var position = arr[i].position;
    if (position > currentPosition) {
      return i - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

> Please find a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ayyub/rmph3Lv0/21/

Comment: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @AyyubKolsawala thanks but I've managed to make it work as my function was good but I was running it before changing the index so the result was equal with previews `currentPosition` here it is `const previewsIndexes = PLAYLIST.filter(
      index => currentPosition > index.position
    );` then `this.index = previewsIndexes.length - 1;`